# Using MIN(TIMESTAMP) in WHERE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

First off, I am a beginner in SQL just learning and I am stuck on one problem looked everywhere but not able to find an answer for it.

```
SCHEMA: time_ts TIMESTAMP,id BYTES,sale_amount FLOAT,client STRING.
```

The report I am trying to export is the clients who are newly acquired within the last 12 months that has made 2 and 3 purchase over the last 12 months as well.

```
DATA SAMPLE:
Row time_ts id  sale_amount client   
1   2011-12-02 16:17:01.280 UTC James   97.67   104795   
2   2010-03-29 19:43:07.723 UTC Mark    90.0    106186   

EXPECTED RES
Number_of_Orders Revenue_Total Year Total_Num_of_orders
1, 100$ 2010 60
2, 150$ 2010 65
```

What I have so far ( Which returns 0 results):

```
SELECT client, COUNT(id) AS sales, MIN(time_ts),
FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.comments]
WHERE time_ts >= TIMESTAMP(time_ts) > DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), -12, 'MONTH')
GROUP BY client
HAVING COUNT(id) = 2;
```

Comment: What's your expect result and provide some sample data?

Comment: Add sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: Just added sample data and expected results.

Comment: I cannot understand the link between your expected result and sample data. Could you explain more detail?

Comment: Yes i am using BigQuery, and the dataset is public data set. Maybe this will help explain the link. I need to prepare a report to evaluating customers purchase based on acquisition time. The main question the report should answer is, if someone that was acquired in last 12M (months) and has ordered last 12M. I need to compare customers that bought once, twice, thrice, or more than 3 times.  

The report must have results shown in order numbers and revenue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  But the condition in the `where` needs to be in the `having`:

```
SELECT client, COUNT(id) AS sales, MIN(time_ts),
FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.comments]
GROUP BY client
HAVING COUNT(id) = 2 AND
       MIN(time_ts) > DATE_ADD(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW()), -12, 'MONTH');
```

I am assuming that the date arithmetic is right.  I stopped using legacy SQL a while ago and you should use standard SQL as well.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks for the help & tip, I will move to standard SQL.

Comment: J.Awesome, you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Done, i'm new here didn't know i had to accept the answer thanks for informing me Xiaoxia